# How to combine two images with different gains in Matlab/ C++

Tags: c++, image, matlab, image-processing

I have two images, both taken at the same time from the same detector.

Both images have **11 bit** resolution (yes, its odd but that is the case here). The difference between the two images is that one image as been amplified by a factor of  **1** and the other has been amplified by a factor of **10**.

How can I take these two **11 bit** images, and combine their pixel values to get a single **16 bit** image?  Basically, this increases the dynamic range of the final image.

I am fairly new to image processing. I know there is a solution for this, since other systems do this on the fly pixel-by-pixel in an FPGA. I was just hoping to be able to do this in Matlab post processing instead of live. I know doing bitwise operations in Matlab can be kinda difficult, but we do have an educational license with every toolbox available.

As mentioned below, this look an awful lot like HDR processing. The goal isn't artistic, rather data preservation. This is eventually going to be put in C++ and flown on an autonomous flight computer and running standard bloated HDR software on the fly would kill our timing requirements

Thanks for the help!

As a side note, I'd like to be able to do this for any combination of gains. ie 2x and 30x, 4x and 8x ect. In my gut I feel like this is a deceptively simple algorithm or interpolation, but I just don't know where to start.

**Gains**

Since there is some confusion on what the gains mean, I'll try to explain. The image sensor (CMOS) being used on our custom camera has the capability to simultaneously output two separate images, both taken from the same exposure. It can do this because the sensor has **2** different electrical amplifiers along its data path.

In photography terms, it would be like your DSLR being able to take a picture using **2** different ISO values at the same time.

Sorry for the confusion

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "combine their pixel values"?

Comment: Why is this not just a case of adding the two image matrices together, possibly also with multiplication by constants?

Comment: Kol-Sorry if this is ambiguous. I want to represent each pixel as a 'combination' of both the low gain and high gain version of that pixel. The LG/HG pixels are each represented by an 11 bit number. Having different gains applied (by the camera) to each means that both LG/HG pixels have information that the other does not. I want to combine the two to increase my dynamic range.

Comment: Oli-Is this the case? I really don't know the theory behind this. I just don't know how this works. Both pixels have an integer range of 0-2^11. But that number represents a different scale of the exposure value/pixel value. So I don't know if simply adding gives me what I need. I guess that is where I am hung up. Thanks!

Comment: Twerdster-Really productive. If you look at my questions, I do indeed accept relevant answers. I do **not** accept tangental thoughts and discussions. I know I don't ask easy questions, and I only ask things that I've truly been unable to solve, but thats what this is for right? I'm big on this community, don't let a single statistic make up your mind about me from afar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems you pose is known as ["High Dynamic Range Imaging"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_dynamic_range_image) and ["Tone Mapping"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping). I suggest you start with those Wikipedia articles, then drill down to the bibliography cited therein.

You don't provide enough details about your imagery to give a more specific answer. What is the "gain" you mention? Did you crank up the sensor's gain (to what ISO-equivalent number?), or did you use a longer exposure time? Are the 11-bit pixel values linear or already gamma-compressed?

Comment: Snap! I never even thought to try to HDR process the pictures! Thanks for the starting point. I'll look into the back-end algorithms  and try them out. I will leave the question opened for a time, in case somebody knows the actual programming required to accomplish this. Thanks!  Also, I edited the question to include more info on "gains"

Answer (score 0):

To upscale an 11bit range to a 16bit range multiple by (2^16-1)/(2^11-1).
*(**Assuming you want a linear scaling.** (Which is reasonable when scaling up.)*

If the gain was discrete (applied to the 11bit range), then you have two 11bit images which may have some values saturated.

If the gain was applied in a continuous (analog) or floating point range, then your values can go beyond the original 11bits. Also, if the gain was applied in a continuous (analog) or floating point range, the values were probably scaled to another range first e.g. [0,1] (by dividing by (2^11-1)).
If the values were scaled to another range, you will have to divide by the maximum of the new range instead of by (2^11-1).

Either way (whether gain was in 11bit range or not), due to the gain and due to the addtion, the resulting values may be large than the original range. In this case, you need to decide how you want to scale them:

- Do you want to scale the original 11bit range to 16bit (possible causing saturation)?
  If so multiple by multiple by (2^16-1)/(2^11-1)
- Do you want to scale the maximum possible value to 2^16-1?
  If so multiple by multiple by (2^16-1)/( (2^11-1) * (G1+G2) )
- Do you want to scale the actual maximum value to 2^16-1?
  If so multiple by multiple by (2^16-1)/(max(sum(I1+I2))

Edit:

Since you do not want to add the images, but rather use the different details in them, perhaps this article will help you:

[Digital Photography with Flash and No-Flash Image Pairs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/flashnoflash/)

Comment: Sorry, but the aim isn't to simply represent a single 11-bit image as a 16 bit scaled image, since the information within would essentially remain unchanged. The goal is to use the information from two images to form a single image that each original cannot fully represent.

Comment: a. Your question does not state this. b. There are algorithms for that, however, the images usually come from to photographs of the same scene with different exposure levels (or one with a flash and one without), not two images where one has gain applied. See link in edit.